# Seal translation (Characters identified: 嘉雲)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

[image: any help is appreciated!]

Please help me translate the name of this artist.

Comment: Transliteration is a good choice.
or:
嘉 means beautiful
云 means cloud

Answer (score 2):

This seal says "嘉雲" but it seems I cannot find this artist online. The name of the artist may possibly be Karen as the pronunciation is similar to 嘉雲. Good luck!